# Getting the name of a property in a list

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

**Example**

```
public class MyItems
{
    public object Test1  {get ; set; }
    public object Test2  {get ; set; }
    public object Test3  {get ; set; }
    public object Test4  {get ; set; }
    public List<object> itemList
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<object>
            {
                Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4
            }
        }
    }
}

public void LoadItems()
{
    foreach (var item in MyItems.itemList)
    {
        //get name of item here (asin,  Test1, Test2)
    }
}
```

**

I have tried this with reflection..  asin `typeof(MyItems).GetFields()` etc.. but that doesn't work.

How can I find out which name "item" has? Test1? Test2?? etc...

Comment: You need to use `GetProperties`. Fields are regular class variables.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, refactor/re-think it. A dictionary might be a good option

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, but some objects are / can be null.. and dictionary does not seem to allow null objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var test = typeof(MyItems).GetProperties().Select(c=>c.Name);
```

The above will give you an Enumerable of properties name. 
if you want to get the name of the properties in the list use:

```
var test = typeof(MyItems).GetProperties().Select(c=>c.Name).ToList();
```

EDIT:

From your comment, may be you are looking for :

```
 foreach (var item in m.itemList)
    {
        var test2 = (item.GetType()).GetProperties().Select(c => c.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a bit.. but how can I manage to make it work only for the "item" ?

Comment: Managed to create it with a for loop, lambda expressions and your first solution.

Answer (score 1):

The "name" of the object is neither `"Test1"`, nor `"MyItems[0]"`.

Both those are just references to the object, that is in effect, nameless.

I do not know of any technique in C# that could give you all the references to an object, given an object, so I do not think what you want is possible, the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the name of properties with this code (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx#Y1090))

```
Type myType =(typeof(MyTypeClass));
// Get the public properties.
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);

for(int i=0;i<myPropertyInfo.Length;i++)
{
    PropertyInfo myPropInfo = (PropertyInfo)myPropertyInfo[i];
    Console.WriteLine("The property name is {0}.", myPropInfo.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("The property type is {0}.", myPropInfo.PropertyType);
}
```

But right now I **don't know any code** to *access the name of a reference*!